# Filtrar datos de un Data.frame por detección de caracteres

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Sucede que tengo mucha información contenida en un `Data.frame` donde se puede observar los siguientes velores en las filas dentro del `Data.frame`.

```
Product list: Meat
Product list: Juice
Product list: Bread
Product list: Rice
...
```

Lo que necesito es poder filtrar esta información por medio de una detección de carácteres en este caso sería `Product` el carácter a detectar.

Después de tener ese filtro, necesitaría dividir ese mismo carácter por ejemplo `Product list: Meat`, en dos columnas, la primera columna sería `Product List` y la segunda `Meat`, en general busco separar lo que está antes y después del los dos puntos(:).

Muchas gracias.

Comment: No entiendo bien si el valor que muestras es literal (es decir, se trata exactamente de ese texto), o es una plantilla generalque puede aparecer en varias filas y en cada una ser diferente la parte "list of names" (o incluso diferente el nombre del producto). Por otro lado, ¿Es `Produc`  o `Product`?

Comment: Exacto, en cada fila puede aparecer un diferente valor después de los dos puntos (:), el Product List siempre es fijo por eso es que necesito utlizar la deteccion de carácter como Product. Y sí, tienes razón, es Product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A falta de un ejemplo por tu parte, voy a crear yo uno artificialmente.

El código que pongo a continuación no es parte de la respuesta, sino que sirve para crear un dataframe artificial que creo que tiene una estructura como la que tú indicas, y que servirá después para ilustrar la solución:

```
import pandas as pd
import random
random.seed(1)  # Para que el ejemplo sea reproducible


# Lista con los nombres de los productos
# En este caso serían Prod1, Prod2, Prod3,... Prod20
productos = ["Prod{}".format(i) for i in range(1,21)]

n_filas = 10  # Numero de filas a generar

def genera_fila():
  # Una fila puede contener aleatoriamente o bien una cadena como la indicada
  # en el enunciado del problema, en cuyo caso la lista de productos tras los
  # dos puntos se elige aleatoriamente, o bien la cadena "Otra cosas"
  if random.random()<0.5:
    return "Product list: {}".format(", ".join(random.sample(productos, random.randint(1,5))))
  else:
    return "Otra cosa"


# Generar un dataframe de ejemplo con estos datos
contenidos = [genera_fila() for i in range(n_filas)]
precios = [random.uniform(0,40) for i in range(n_filas)]
df = pd.DataFrame({"Caso": contenidos, "Precio": precios})
```

El dataframe generado tiene esta pinta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora queremos:

1. Quedarnos sólo con las filas que, en la columna "Caso", comiencen por la cadena `"Product "`. Esto podemos hacerlo usando el operador `.str.startswith()` sobre esa columna y seleccionando las que den `True`.
2. Partir la columna resultante por los dos puntos, y supongo que asignar la lista de productos a la derecha de los dos puntos a otra columna del dataframe. Para partir la columna se puede usar `str.split(":", expand=True)` que crea un nuevo dataframe con tantas columnas como "trozos" se hayan generado. Sólo nos interesa el trozo`[1]`. Para asignarlo a una nueva columna del dataframe podemos usar `.assign()`

El siguiente código hace ambas cosas en una sola línea

```
filtrado = (df[df.Caso.str.startswith("Product ")]
            .assign(Productos = lambda x: x.Caso.str.split(":", expand=True)[1])
           )
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que genio. Muchas gracias

Comment: Una pregunta, cuando se usa la función str.split("", expand = true), a que me refieron con la parte de expand?.